# Saving numpy.ndarray in python as an image

Tags: python

```
b=ndimage.gaussian_filter(imagefile,5)
```

Being new to python, not able to figure this out.
how to save `b` as an image, `b` is of  type 'numpy.ndarray'?

Tried these,
1.

```
im = Image.fromarray(b)   
im.save("newfile.jpeg")
```

`Error: TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")`

2.

```
imsave('newfile.jpg', b)
```

`Error: ValueError: 'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for any mode.`

Which is the right way to save an `ndarray` into an image?

EDIT:

Solved:

```
im = Image.fromarray(b)
```

`im.save('newfile.jpeg')` worked, The way I was loading the image was wrong,

```
file = Image.open("abc.jpg")      
imagefile = file.load()
```

// I was using imagefile after loading, which was not giving proper shape to reconstruct the image.

// Instead If I use file (i.e. directly after opening, I can save by above method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best approach is using `matplotlib` `imshow`.

using the `image` library:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)

im = Image.fromarray(x)
im.save('test.png')
```

Matplotlib Version:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
plt.imshow(x) 
plt.savefig("array")
```

[image: Output of ndarray]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me try, I would like to avoid importing few more libraries to just save an array as image.

Comment: You can add your previous answer of saving the image, I can save it that way, provided I read the image properly, I have edited the question.